# groupby common values in two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need to extract a common max value from pairs of rows that have common values in two columns.

The commonality is between values in columns A and B. Rows 0 and 1 are common, 2 and 3, and 4 is on its own.

```
f = DataFrame([[1, 2, 30], [2, 1, 20], [2, 6, 15], [6, 2, 70], [7, 10, 35]], columns=['A', 'B', 'Value'])
f
   A   B  Value
0  1   2     30
1  2   1     20
2  2   6     15
3  6   2     70
4  7  10     35
```

The goal is to extract max values, so the end result is:

```
f_final = DataFrame([[1, 2, 30, 30], [2, 1, 20, 30], [2, 6, 15, 70], [6, 2, 70, 70], [7, 10, 35, 35]], columns=['A', 'B', 'Value', 'Max'])
f_final

   A   B  Value  Max
0  1   2     30   30
1  2   1     20   30
2  2   6     15   70
3  6   2     70   70
4  7  10     35   35
```

I could do this if there is a way to assign a common, non-repeating key:

```
f_key = DataFrame([[1, 1, 2, 30], [1, 2, 1, 20], [2, 2, 6, 15], [2, 6, 2, 70], [3, 7, 10, 35]], columns=['key', 'A', 'B', 'Value'])
f_key

   key  A   B  Value
0    1  1   2     30
1    1  2   1     20
2    2  2   6     15
3    2  6   2     70
4    3  7  10     35
```

Following up with the groupby and transform:

```
f_key['Max'] = f_key.groupby(['key'])['Value'].transform(lambda x: x.max())
f_key.drop('key', 1, inplace=True)
f_key

   A   B  Value  Max
0  1   2     30   30
1  2   1     20   30
2  2   6     15   70
3  6   2     70   70
4  7  10     35   35
```

Question 1:
How would one assign this common key?

Question 2:
Is there a better way of doing this, skipping the common key step

Cheers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort the values in columns `A` and `B` so that for each row the value in `A` is less than or equal to the value in `B`. Once the values are ordered, then you could apply `groupby-transform-max` as usual:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 30], [2, 1, 20], [2, 6, 15], [6, 2, 70], [7, 10, 35]],
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'Value'])
mask = df['A'] > df['B']
df.loc[mask, ['A','B']] = df.loc[mask, ['B','A']].values
df['Max'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['Value'].transform('max')

print(df)
```

yields

```
   A   B  Value  Max
0  1   2     30   30
1  1   2     20   30
2  2   6     15   70
3  2   6     70   70
4  7  10     35   35
```

---

The above method will still work even if the values in `A` and `B` are strings.  For example,

```
df = DataFrame([['ab', 'ac', 30], ['ac', 'ab', 20],
                 ['cb', 'ca', 15], ['ca', 'cb', 70],
                 ['ff', 'zz', 35]], columns=['A', 'B', 'Value'])

mask = df['A'] > df['B']
df.loc[mask, ['A','B']] = df.loc[mask, ['B','A']].values
df['Max'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['Value'].transform('max')
```

yields

```
In [267]: df
Out[267]: 
    A   B  Value  Max
0  ab  ac     30   30
1  ab  ac     20   30
2  ca  cb     15   70
3  ca  cb     70   70
4  ff  zz     35   35
```

Comment: Thanks @unutbu. Is there a similar approach with the strings?
    
    df = DataFrame([['ab', 'ac', 30], ['ac', 'ab', 20], 
                   ['cb', 'ca', 15], ['ca', 'cb', 70], 
                   ['ff', 'zz', 35]], columns=['A', 'B', 'Value'])

Comment: Ah, in that case, geometry is not going to help -- unless you convert the values to factors first. But that would probably negate the speed advantage.

Comment: Used Categorical and get_indexer. Seem to work. Thanks for help.

   c =  pd.Categorical.from_array(df.A)
   idx = c.levels
   df['A1'] = idx.get_indexer(df.A)
   df['B1'] = idx.get_indexer(df.B)

Comment: That may not work since `idx.get_indexer(df.B)` will return -1 wherever the value in `B` is not in `A`. Thus, `(ff, zz)` and `(ff, qq)` would both be mapped to something like `(4, -1)`.

Comment: @coredump: The first method still works even if the values are strings.

Comment: It's not the most performant, but there's also `df["Value"].groupby(map(frozenset,df[["A","B"]].values),sort=False).transform(max)`.